How to annotate, filter then get ForeignKey field relations in Django (FilteredRelation or another method)?
I'm trying to annotate ForeignKey relations and then use new annotated field in loop
From docs:
>>> from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, Q
>>> Restaurant.objects.annotate(
...     pizzas_vegetarian=FilteredRelation(
...         "pizzas",
...         condition=Q(pizzas__vegetarian=True),
...     ),
... ).filter(pizzas_vegetarian__name__icontains="mozzarella")

That works.
But if I do:
>>> from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, Q
>>> rests = Restaurant.objects.annotate(
...     pizzas_vegetarian=FilteredRelation(
...         "pizzas",
...         condition=Q(pizzas__vegetarian=True),
...     )
... )
... for rest in rests:
        print(rest.pizzas_vegetarian)

I get

AttributeError: "Restaurant object has no attribute 'pizzas_vegetarian'"

I need access to that "pizzas_vegetarian" in separate code blocks.
Is it possible with FilteredRelation?
Which method should I use to get it?
UPDATE
Above code is from Django docs.
But in my case each restaurant has 'pizzas', and each pizza can only be of one type: 1, 2, 3.
What i need: when querying restaurants (in one query), to each restaurant in queryset set field pizza1, pizza2, pizza3 - these fields may be model instance of related pizzas or None.
Looks like I need just create these pizza1, pizza2, pizza3 fields inside my Restaurant model, but i'm really trying to avoid it.

The .annotate(…) [Django-doc] does not create an attribute on the Restaurant objects, this is used to do further filtering, annotating, etc. in the QuerySet.
What you need here is a Prefetch object [Django-doc] that can populate a relation in a filtered matter:
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'pizzas',
        Pizza.objects.filter(vegitarian=True),
        to_attr='pizzas_vegetarian',
    )
)
If you know for sure there is at most one such vegiterian pizza, you can also retrieve it with .select_related(…) [Django-doc]:
Restaurant.objects.annotate(
    pizzas_vegetarian=FilteredRelation(
        'pizzas',
        condition=Q(pizzas__vegetarian=True),
    ),
).select_related('pizzas_vegetarian')
I'm however not sure if that is a feature or essentially was an (unintended) side-effect of the FilteredRelation logic.

unfortunately "pizzas_vegetarian" in that case will be list, not model instance. (And looks like in that code Pizza is not linked with Restaurant by ForeignKey - all pizzas with vegitarian=True will be in result, but we need only related with exactly restaurant)

@user3905355: they are, if the Pizza is related to the restaurant through the pizzas relation (the first item of the ManyToManyField). Prefetch fetches the relation. The fact that it is a collection (list) makes perfect sense, since it is not said that a Restaurant has only one vegetarian pizza.

@user3905355: Prefetch operates on a relation, and does the "JOIN process" at the Django layer. It thus fetches the filtered Pizza queryset, looks what the relation is (for example m2m), then fetches the m2m records, and joins the Pizzas to the corresponding Restaurants. But the veggie pizza is not repeated per Restaurant if that Pizza was not linked to the restaurant in the first place.

Yep, it's perfect to get list in that expample. In my case i really need field to be model instance (or None), not list. I mean, i need exact pizza in field (like Pizza.objects.filter(id=1))

@user3905355: well you can "unpack" it from the list. But it is a bit strange. If you really know there is one veggie pizza per restaurant, it makes more sense to query in the opposite direction: use Pizza as "base model" and fetch the restaurant along with it.

@user3905355: you can also work with .select_related(..) on a FilteredRelation, although I don't know if this was an intended use.

My bad, i used example from Django docs. In my case each restaurant has 'pizzas', and each pizza can only be of one type: 1, 2, 3. What i need: when querying restaurants (in one query), to each restaurant in queryset set field pizza1, pizza2, pizza3 - in these fields may be model instance of related pizzas or None. Looks like I need just create these pizza1, pizza2, pizza3 fields inside my  Restaurant model, but i'm trying to avoid it.

@user3905355: you can thus use the .annotate(..) trick in combination with .select_related(..) on that FilteredRelation (see edit).
